# How to use Jaspersoft Studio reports in Fishbowl Inventory

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I use Fishbowl Inventory, which allows custom reports. It supports Jaspersoft iReport. iReport was retired long ago and I can't even get it to run. It's successor is Jaspersoft Studio but the reports compiled are not accepted by Fishbowl.

I know some people have succeeded in using Studio to create reports that run on Fishbowl. The one thing I've seen is to is set Studio's compatibility to version 5.5.0. I did that but Fishbowl still rejects it. Any suggestions?